# Why is my python plotting code runs so slow after I add the legend?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a scatter plot in pandas and it runs fine. But after I add the legend, it runs really slow and got stuck. Can anyone help me, please?

```
fcdp_data_100HZ[['Second','totCNTs']].plot.scatter(x="Second", y="totCNTs",color='royalblue',s=100,alpha=0.5, ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_title("Counts")
axes[1].grid()
axes[1].set_ylim([1,100])
axes[1].set_yscale('log')
axes[1].set_ylabel("Counts")
axes[1].legend(['100HZ'])

fcdp_data_20HZ[['Second','totCNTs']].plot.scatter(x="Second", y="totCNTs",color='coral', s=100,alpha=0.5, ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_title("Counts")
axes[1].grid()
axes[1].set_ylim([1,100])
axes[1].set_yscale('log')
axes[1].set_ylabel("Counts")
axes[1].legend(['20HZ'])

fcdp_data_1HZ[['Second','totCNTs']].plot.scatter(x="Second", y="totCNTs",color='darkslategrey',s=100,alpha=0.5, ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_title("Counts")
axes[1].grid()
axes[1].set_ylim([1,100])
axes[1].set_yscale('log')
axes[1].set_ylabel("Counts")
axes[1].legend(['1HZ'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: the default legend location is "auto" which needs to search for a good place to put the legend.  Try placing it manually (ie.. `loc='upper right'`)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `label="100HZ"` or whatever your label is to each plotting function and call legend once at the end.